# Error with Json http request iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, internal-server-error, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to work on Livelink restful services and get data in iOS Application. The documentation link for api is:

https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=%2Fawd%2Fresources%2Fapis%2Fcontent-server-v1.1%23!%2Fauth

Code I am using for getting response data is:

```
NSDictionary *authDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"XYZ",@"username",
                              @"ABC",@"password",
                              nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:authDict options:0 error:&error];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://livelink.xyz.com/livelink/livelink.exe/api/v1/auth"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];                                              
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But in request reply I am not getting authentication result.When I log request reply,the log is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please help me to get the Authentication ticket. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about iOS stuff much but may be it can help you. I am using ajax to get ticket and it works:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var url = "your url/api/v1";
      var credentials = { username: "USERNAME", password: "PASSWORD" };

      $.post(url + "/auth", credentials, function (response) {
        var ticket = response.ticket;
        alert(response)
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>Hi</body>
</html>
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Yes I am trying upto same steps in iOS code but there it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

By adding a semicolon between the 2 values:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

My recommendation is to work with Async:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"requestReply = \n[%@]", string);
}];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}
```

But it looks like the error you have is related to the server you are trying to access, please make sure that http://livelink.xyz.com/livelink/livelink.exe/api/v1/auth is accessible and exist. Please take a look your server configuration.

The following error:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

This error is related to server side, nothing to do with your client.

If you search the description of the error, it looks like you are using a Microsoft web server, please take a look: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942031

Other than that your code looks fine for me.

Comment: But same thing is working with as provided in iOSMobiler answer below. It is not working with iOS Code.